# check order of numbers C++

Tags: c++, set, sequence

I want to design a method for checking numbers sequence in a std::set
   For example, I have

```
set [1,3,4]
```

I can figure out there is number 2 missing in the set,
   What I can do is to do a loop on the set, and check `(current number - previous number) == 1`, if yes, the loop will continue for next till end. If not, missing number found.

But it seems not good for my method, so I want to know whether there are existing std lib or boost which I can use for this kind of comparison?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you need to report the actual number(s) that are missing, or just that one or more numbers are missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace the for-loop by STL algorithm (C++11):

```
auto it = begin(your_set);
while (it != end(your_set)) {
    it = std::adjacent_find(it,
                            end(your_set),
                            [](int a, int b){ return (b - a) != 1; });
    if (it != end(your_set)) {
      std::cout << "Found gap at: " << *it << std::endl;
      ++it;
    }
}
```

This will find all gaps in your set.

Lambda functions, `auto` keyword and standalone begin/end are new features in C++11.

Comment: You may want to explain the use of lambda, as the user may not be very familiar with it.

Comment: +1 but I think you could improve the answer by pointing out that the returned iterator tells you *which* (if any) number is the first missing one.

Comment: [](int a, int b){ return b - a != 1; } is it to defined a temporary function inside? I have an issue when compiling it.  expected primary-expression before '[' token

Comment: Which compiler do you use? I used C++11 features. Lambda functions can be replaced by either functor, or pointer to normal function with same functionality.

Comment: GCC 4.3, I think I have limitation on this feature, but thank you very much ;p

Comment: Lambdas are supported by GCC since version 4.5. I think.

Answer (score -3):

You can also do that with recursion. The proposed solution is in Java, but should be portable to C++ very easily.

```
public boolean isSequenceValid(int[] sequence) {
    if (sequence.length == 0) return true;

    return isNumberValid(sequence, 0, sequence[0]);
}

private boolean isNumberValid(int[] sequence, int index, int expectedValue) {
    if (index >= sequence.length) return true;
    if (sequence[index] != expectedValue) return false;

    return isNumberValid(sequence, index+1, expectedValue+1);
}
```

Comment: Do you care that much? That's an algorithmic problem, not a language one. I just proposed a generic solution without using any library or framework... I just wanted to help in a different way.

Comment: I don't mind, and I didn't downvote. I just thought it might have not been intentional.